# How to read dumpbin for windows library (.lib)?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dumpbin

We're using `zlib.lib` in our project and after some rebuild of this lib I can no longer compile a project. One of the errors says:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflateEnd referenced in function lws_extension_callback_deflate_frame
```

I `dumpbin`'ed my library and here what I have:

```
013 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | deflateEnd
027 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | deflateEnd
013 000013B0 SECT5  notype ()    External     | deflateEnd
044 0000000C SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$deflateEnd
045 0000000C SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$deflateEnd
00E 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | deflateEnd
```

How to read it?

1. Why symbol `013` appeared twice?
2. Why the second column contain zeros mostly and only one have numbers. What are this numbers?
3. What does `notype` mean? Why sometimes there're braces `()` and sometimes - not?
4. What `External` means?
5. What are this `$unwind$` and `$pdata$`?
6. And finally, having all this information is it possible to say why I have unresolved symbol?

Comment: I didn't find documentation, so I'm just guessing: 
External are symbols that are expected to be satisfied by another library, just like the keyword external in C code implies. $unwind$ and $pdata$ are both meant for exception handling (SEH). see http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731157033.htm for a more detailed explanation

Comment: External in this case means it's visible externally. "The fifth column (Static, External) tells whether the symbol is visible only within that object, or whether it is public (visible externally). A Static symbol, _sym, wouldn't be linked to a Public symbol _sym; these would be two different instances of functions named _sym.  " - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx